# Как импортировать jquery-плагины в webpack?

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack, плагин

Есть самописный плагин jquery примерно такого вида:

```
$.fn.simpleParallax = function() {
    var act = function() {...};
    return this.each(act);
};
```

Собираю проект на Webpack. Положил свой плагин в отдельный файл вот так:

```
module.exports = function(){ ... }
```

импортировал туда же jquery `const $ = require('jquery')`, потом в главном скрипте делаю `(require('мой плагин'))()`.
Работает. Но в проекте есть ещё пара jquery-плагинов (они чужие и ничего никуда не экспортируют) - лезть "под капот", импортировать туда `jquery`, городить `module.exports`... Это уже совсем не выглядит как хорошая идея.
Так каков правильный способ подключения подобных вещей?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В подключаемый модуль можно автоматически добавить импорт при помощи загрузчика imports-loader (который сперва должен быть установлен).
Например:

```
import 'imports-loader?$=jquery!./js/myPlugin';
```

Подключенный таким способом плагин при сборке обзаведётся вот такой строкой:

```
/*** IMPORTS FROM imports-loader ***/
var $ = __webpack_require__(0);
```

**webpack_require**(0) в данном случае возвращает модуль jquery, подключенный в моей сборке под номером 0